# Convert HTML to Plain Text using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have to convert HTML code to plain text using python, For example..for below html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="Myclass">
            <p> All my class is doing good  </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i convert this html , it should provide me ..

```
<html><body><div class="Myclass"><p> All my class is doing good
</p></div></body></html>
```

with proper line break and in proper justification.

Below is my code ,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<html><body><div class="Myclass"><p> All my class is doing good</p></div></body></html>

'''
myhtml=html.replace(">\n",">")
print(myhtml)

import re
mny = '\n'.join(re.findall('.{1,20}', myhtml))
print(mny)
```

but the result shows something like this

```
<html><body><div cla
ss="Myclass"><p> All
 my class is doing g
ood</p></div></body>
</html>
```

it truncates class **<div cla** like this , is there any way to fix this.
`
Output should be something like this.

```
<html><body><div class="Myclass">
<p> All my class is doing good
</p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: `'.{1,20}'` is doing its job of taking the first 20 chars

Comment: How is the expected output different from the input? Both are HTML, the expected output is not "plain text".